# Playing AVI files in C# and changing the brightness of the video

Tags: c#, video, avi, brightness

I need to run avi files in C# windows application, and according to a percentage the user specify, the video will dim in and out.

Any help, first to run avi files in the first place. 
Note : I tried to work with Windows.DirectX, but i couldn't reference this library from my code at all !

Comment: Windows Forms or WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Add Windows Media PLayer: Add Reference --> COM --> Windows Media Player,
Add it to ToolBox --> Choose Item --> COM Components --> Windows Media Player,
Add a player to your form - it comes with volume, skip, play, stop, pause and the time bar.

To change brightness I would change the screen's brightness(this is a simple way to do it - you could also set that when the video is not playing the brightness returns to its previous state):

```
using System.Management;
//...
static void SetBrightness(byte targetBrightness) {
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\WMI");
    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods");
    using(ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query)) {
        using(ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = searcher.Get()) {
            foreach(ManagementObject mObj in objectCollection) {
                mObj.InvokeMethod("WmiSetBrightness",
                    new Object[] { UInt32.MaxValue, targetBrightness });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, but the thing is that i am trying to run the video without using any player, and i want the brightness to be changed on the video itself not the screen, 
Any ideas ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: @NadaNaeem sorry - that's all I can think of. Couldn't find any instructions on the Web. Please do post when you find the answer as I'm sure many people are searching for it. Good luck!